# What exactly is an AMI in AWS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm bit confused about what purpose does the AMI serve.
Is AMI something which provides a platform with particular OS and other configurations to access the instance?

Comment: This is one explanation - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/ec2-instances-and-amis.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is pretty much what it's name implies - a machine image.  There is, for example, a variety of Linux images.  You can use an image to create a Linux instance.  The AMI is not "used up" during the use - it can be used any number of times.  There are also images that have an operating system such a Linux *and* software - for example a database server or a closed source server or pretty much anything you can imagine.

Think of the AMI as something you would use as the source for a copy machine.  On the source paper there may be a little or a lot.  The copier creates a new page that has whatever was on the source page.  And you can make any number of copies.

Access to the instance varies on the AMI.  A Linux one usually opens an `ssh` port while a Windows one usually uses some sort of remote desktop.  The AWS console can guide you a bit but usually you'll need some documentation to know how to use the instance created from the AMI to know how to use it.

Answer (score 2):

An Amazon Machine Image (AMI) is basically a **copy of the disk** that will be attached to a newly-launched instance. It is normally just the boot disk, but an AMI can actually contain multiple disk images.

The AMI is 'copied' to the disk of the newly launched instance. (Not quite accurate, but you can think of it that way.) Changes to the local disk do *not* impact the AMI.

AWS provides a number of AMIs with **pre-loaded operating systems** such as Windows, Amazon Linux and Ubuntu. Some of them contain additional software, such as Windows with SQL Server.

There are also **community AMIs** that are created by somebody other than AMI, but shared to all users. For example, a company might load a **demo version of their software** onto the AMI, so customers can simply launch an Amazon EC2 instance and it will have all software already loaded and configured.

An AMI is actually just a Snapshot, plus additional metadata. However, a Snapshot can only be restored to an Amazon EBS volume, whereas an AMI can be used to launch an instance. The Amazon EC2 service will then load the disk and attach it to the new instance.